# How to use verbatim with tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox, verbatim

The following gives many strange errors:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[fit,height=5cm,blank, borderline={1pt}{-2pt},nobeforeafter]
\begin{verbatim}
[83 democrat / 66 republican]
| | a_b_c = y: [28 democrat / 64 republican]
\end{verbatim}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

including "Missing $ inserted", "Double subscript", so `verbatim` isn't working. Without `tcolorbox` the code works fine. How can I use `verbatim` with `tcolorbox`?

Comment: For those of us who may not be very familiar with tcolorbox, can you include a complete document (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`)? For example, with some experimentation I was able to reproduce your error with `\usepackage{tcolorbox}` `\tcbuselibrary{fitting}` `\tcbuselibrary{skins}` but I don't know if you did the same things.

Comment: Please also provide the full and exact text of the error message you get when compiling the (completed) code you provide. This will include, for example, the line number corresponding to the relevant line in your example.

Comment: Section '7 Saving and Loading of Verbatim Texts'. Page 126 of `tcolorbox`'s manual. 22.1 `/tcb/verbatim` page 423.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It runs.  I hope the options are what you intended.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{fitting,skins}
\usepackage{listings}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}
\setbox\tempbox=\hbox{\begin{lstlisting}
[83 democrat / 66 republican]
| | a_b_c = y: [28 democrat / 64 republican]
\end{lstlisting}}

\begin{tcolorbox}[fit,height=5cm,blank, borderline={1pt}{-2pt},nobeforeafter]
\usebox\tempbox
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `listings` to emulate plain verbatim, using a language that has nothing at all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\lstdefinelanguage{none}{}

\newtcblisting{tcbverbatim}{
  fit,
  height=5cm,
  blank,
  borderline={1pt}{-2pt},
  %nobeforeafter,
  listing only,
  listing options={
    language=none,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    columns=flexible,
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbverbatim}
[83 democrat / 66 republican]
| | a_b_c = y: [28 democrat / 64 republican]
\end{tcbverbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`tcolorbox` has a mechanism to define fully-fledged color box verbatim environment:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{qwr}{listing only,fit,height=5cm,blank, borderline={1pt}{-2pt},nobeforeafter}

\begin{document}
\begin{qwr}
[83 democrat / 66 republican]
| | a_b_c = y: [28 democrat / 64 republican]
\end{qwr}
\end{document}
```