# How to Set Background Color for verbatim Formatted Content Longer Than a Single Page?

Tags: overleaf, verbatim, code-snippets

My goal is to include lengthy example code that exceeds a single page, and I would like to set a background color for this code. The native verbatim environment allows content to span multiple pages, but it doesn't support background color, so I'm looking for alternative approaches.

I've explored some existing solutions on various forums, but none of them seem to meet my requirements:

1. The method mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141128/302017) involves using a box,
   which prevents the content from breaking across pages.
2. The solution in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53951/302017) does allow content
   to break across pages, but it introduces faint white lines between
   lines of code, affecting readability.
3. This [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15942/302017) also tried to solve the problem, but there is uncomfortable lines between snippet as well.([This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62202/302017) asked a similar question around 11 years ago but still no decent solution through its answers)
4. [Change the background color of native verbatim](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9036/302017) would not work either
5. Other solutions, including
   utilizing mdframed to break a box across pages, still fail to fully
   address the issue.

Could you please advise me on how to proceed?

---

For example, implementing fancyvrb and box would be perfect with content less than 1 page, but how to make it better with longer code like below ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,newverbs,xcolor}

\definecolor{cverbbg}{gray}{0.93}

\newenvironment{lcverbatim}
 {\SaveVerbatim{cverb}}
 {\endSaveVerbatim
  \flushleft\fboxrule=0pt\fboxsep=.5em
  \colorbox{cverbbg}{%
    \makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\BUseVerbatim{cverb}}%
  }
  \endflushleft
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lcverbatim}
// sensor_data.json
{
    "time": "2023-05-12T00:47:00.496Z", 
    "f1": "xxx1",
    "ws1": "WS1",
    "m1": "M1",
    "e1": "ETP",
    "o1": "OTP",
    "temp": 1.12"
}
// ingest spec part
{
  …,
  "dataSource": "sensor_data",
  "spec": {
    "dataSchema": {
      "timestampSpec": {
        "column": "time",
        "format": "iso"
      },
      "dimensionsSpec": {
        "dimensions": [
          "f1",
          "ws",
          "m1",
          "e1",
          "o1"
        ]
      },
      "metricsSpec": [
        {
          "name": "temp",
          "type": "doubleSum",
          "fieldName": "temp"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

// ingest spec part 2
{
  …,
  "dataSource": "sensor_data",
  "spec": {
    "dataSchema": {
      "timestampSpec": {
        "column": "time",
        "format": "iso"
      },
      "dimensionsSpec": {
        "dimensions": [
          "f1",
          "ws",
          "m1",
          "e1",
          "o1"
        ]
      },
      "metricsSpec": [
        {
          "name": "temp",
          "type": "doubleSum",
          "fieldName": "temp"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

\end{lcverbatim}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [`tcolorbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) provides boxes with page breaks and also supports listings. BTW: It would be easier to give a concrete answer, if you would [show, what you've tried](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), to see the problems you have had.

Comment: @cabohah Thank you and I've added example code, really appreciate for your kindness

Comment: @cabohah I found this post (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/414034/302017) using tcolorbox as verbatim but faied to break page as well..

Comment: tcolorbox should work fine, and instead of searching only the internet, look into the documentation. It has lots of examples.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your advice. But if there are so many related questions on the website without any available answers, does this imply that there should be a dedicated thread discussing this issue?

Comment: A Q&A site is not a replacement for reading the documentation.

Comment: There can be several reasons for missing answers, e.g., missing information in the question, lack of recognizability of own commitment of the questioner, unclear question, missing focus to really one question, and — last and maybe even least — nobody has an idea. But asking focused questions with minimal working example after searching for already existing solutions, mostly results in answers.

Comment: @cabohah thank you. By 'found no available answers' I mean this could be a meaningful question for many beginners so that I decided to create this post, and, as you suggested, I have edited the post to add MWE which produced unexpected result

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Of course not, but points to a 500+ pages manual with no more concrete comment is really a disappointing even for this simple question.

Comment: The documentation of tcolorbox is quite good, it is well structured, has a table of contents, an index and lots of examples. You do not have to read 500 pages if you know how to handle  such a documentation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks a lot for your kind reply, though I'm left wondering if, perhaps, about 90% of those Stack Overflow responses about Java, Python, etc., could just point to a manual which is well strucutured as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already told: You can use `tcolorbox`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}% needs enabling of shell-escape

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{colback=gray!50,breakable,listing only}
// sensor_data.json
{
    "time": "2023-05-12T00:47:00.496Z", 
    "f1": "xxx1",
    "ws1": "WS1",
    "m1": "M1",
    "e1": "ETP",
    "o1": "OTP",
    "temp": 1.12"
}
// ingest spec part
{
  …,
  "dataSource": "sensor_data",
  "spec": {
    "dataSchema": {
      "timestampSpec": {
        "column": "time",
        "format": "iso"
      },
      "dimensionsSpec": {
        "dimensions": [
          "f1",
          "ws",
          "m1",
          "e1",
          "o1"
        ]
      },
      "metricsSpec": [
        {
          "name": "temp",
          "type": "doubleSum",
          "fieldName": "temp"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

// ingest spec part 2
{
  …,
  "dataSource": "sensor_data",
  "spec": {
    "dataSchema": {
      "timestampSpec": {
        "column": "time",
        "format": "iso"
      },
      "dimensionsSpec": {
        "dimensions": [
          "f1",
          "ws",
          "m1",
          "e1",
          "o1"
        ]
      },
      "metricsSpec": [
        {
          "name": "temp",
          "type": "doubleSum",
          "fieldName": "temp"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{colback=gray!50,breakable,listing only,listing options={basicstyle=\ttfamily,literate={…}{{\dots}}1}}
// sensor_data.json
{
    "time": "2023-05-12T00:47:00.496Z", 
    "f1": "xxx1",
    "ws1": "WS1",
    "m1": "M1",
    "e1": "ETP",
    "o1": "OTP",
    "temp": 1.12"
}
// ingest spec part
{
  …,
  "dataSource": "sensor_data",
  "spec": {
    "dataSchema": {
      "timestampSpec": {
        "column": "time",
        "format": "iso"
      },
      "dimensionsSpec": {
        "dimensions": [
          "f1",
          "ws",
          "m1",
          "e1",
          "o1"
        ]
      },
      "metricsSpec": [
        {
          "name": "temp",
          "type": "doubleSum",
          "fieldName": "temp"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

// ingest spec part 2
{
  …,
  "dataSource": "sensor_data",
  "spec": {
    "dataSchema": {
      "timestampSpec": {
        "column": "time",
        "format": "iso"
      },
      "dimensionsSpec": {
        "dimensions": [
          "f1",
          "ws",
          "m1",
          "e1",
          "o1"
        ]
      },
      "metricsSpec": [
        {
          "name": "temp",
          "type": "doubleSum",
          "fieldName": "temp"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

See the manuals of `tcolorbox` and `listings` for more information.